# Why is $\phi$ constant in the hyperbolic Lorentz transforms?

Tags: special-relativity

If two spacetime events are separated by $(dx,dy,dz,dt),(dx',dy',dz',dt)$  in two reference frames $K,K'$ respectively, whose relative motion is purely along the $x$-axis, then,  purely due to the fact that $$dx^2+dy^2+dz^2-c^2dt^2=dx'^2+dy'^2+dz'^2-c^2dt'^2.....(*)$$
it follows that
$$dx'=dx\cosh\phi+cdt\sinh\phi.....(1)$$
$$cdt'=cdt\cosh\phi+dx\sinh\phi.....(2)$$
for $\phi \in \mathbb{R}.$ Mathematically, any $\phi\in \mathbb{R}$ will satisfy $(*)$, though if $K,K'$ and the two spacetime events are specified, $\phi$ should be fixed.

**Question:** In Landau and Lifshitz, the authors seem to implicitly assume that $\phi$ is solely a function of $K,K'$, and not of the two spacetime events being studied. They make this assumption thusly: they find $\phi$ for the special case of the two events satisfying $dx=0$ (i.e. a particle travelling between the two events travels with speed $0$ relative to $K$), but then insert this value for $\phi$ into $(1),(2)$, not justifying this.

What is the justification for this?

*Note*: In Landau and Lifshitz, they analyse the $x',x,t',t$ equations, not the equations involving their differentials, but they later take differentials of $(1),(2)$, so eventually do what I described above.

Comment: Part of my problem may arise from assuming that the only reason for $(1),(2)$ is $(*)$: I don't know whether that assumption is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the analogy to ordinary co-ordinate axes $x$ and $y$. Let's say you have two sets of axes with the same origin, one rotated with respect to the other by angle $ \theta $ . The coordinates of a point would depend on which set of axes you use but its the distance to the origin would not:

$ x^2 + y^2 = x' ^2+ y'^2         $

The coordinates are related by

$ x' = x \cos \theta - y\sin\theta$

$ y' = x \sin \theta + y\cos\theta$

and $\theta$ depends on the two sets of axes, not the particular point under discussion.

Comment: Thank you. Can the analogy between Euclidean and Minkowski space (specifically, the transformations) be made more rigorous? For instance, [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526087/geometric-interpretation-of-hyperbolic-functions) question I asked on MSE seemed to indicate that there's not much geometric analogy to be made between hyperobolic and usual trigonometric functions, which makes me dubious of such analogies.

Comment: I'm not sure how to make the analogy rigorous, but one thing I should have added to my original reply is that if you substitute (1) and (2) into the RHS of (*) so the primed coordinates are eliminated you can then see that (1) and (2) are transformations that preserve the spacetime interval.

Comment: I make that point in my question and it doesn't follow from that that $\phi$ doesn't depend on the two spacetime co-ordinates being studied.